# Does combining login and password hashing into the same class violate SRP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, authentication, single-responsibility-principle

I have a LoginController class like:

```
class LoginController
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        //Query the database, and get back the password_hash, salt, and user id.
        //Hash the incoming password with the salt.
        //Compare the two hashes.
        //return the logged in user object.
    }
}
```

So, there is a step after retrieving the password_hash and salt from the database where I will need to hash the incoming password. This to me seems like a second responsibility that should be handled by another component. Perhaps a PasswordHashingComponent (or a better name if you've got one).

```
abstract class PasswordHashingComponentAbstract
{
    public abstract function hash($data, $salt = "");

    public function verify($hash, $data, $salt = "")
    {
        return $this->hash($data, $salt) == $hash;
    }
}

class MD5PasswordHashingComponent extends PasswordHashingComponentAbstract
{
    public function hash($data, $salt = "")
    {
        return md5($data . md5($salt));
    }
}

class SHA1PasswordHashingComponent extends PasswordHashingComponentAbstract
{
    public function hash($data, $salt = "")
    {
        return sha1($data . sha1($salt));
    }
}
```

Which I could then dependency inject into the LoginController:

```
public function __construct(PDO $db, PasswordHashingComponentAbstract $passwordhasher);
```

And

```
$loginController = new LoginController($db, new SHA1PasswordHashingComponent());
$loginController->login("username", "password");
```

So my question is whether or not this is overkill.

If my LoginController handles both login as well as how passwords are hashed and compared, is this a major SRP violation?

The way I see it, there are two reasons this class could change:

1. If the way login is handled changes.
2. If the way passwords are hashed and compared changes.

So, doesn't that violate SRP? Is there a better way I could handle abstracting out the password hashing portion?

Thanks!

Comment: For most scenarios it's overkill. But it's nicely engineered overkill, so I won't object. You can even take it a step further: why assume that passwords will be hashed and salted? Stick a `CredentialAuthenticationStrategy` between the `LoginController` and the `HashingComponent`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

A class violates SRP if it has more functionalities and it can be expected that some of those functionalities change independently from each other and that change matters for the maintenance of the class.
This class executes several functions:

1. gets the data from the server side,
2. gets the data from the client side,
3. compares and verifies the data from the client and the server side
4. returns a conclusion to the server side, and
5. returns a conclusion to the client side.

ad 1. this data can consist of different sets of data. It might contain a password, salt, user name, security questions and answers for instance.

ad 2. this data can consist of several pieces of information. Might change overtime and get from different sources (CAPTCHAs and user data). It might be more then only an user name and password.

Client and server side will have some information in common. That information is used to authenticate the user.

ad 3. the comparison method is used for different sets of data from the client and server side.

ad 4. you might decide to do something on the server side after a successful or unsuccessful login like storing the number of unsuccessful logins by a certain account or IP address or you might change the stored salt and password.

ad 5. successful or not, the client will have to get a message in return.

1, 2 and 3 change together, 1 and 4 might have connections in common, 2 and 5 have a functional connection in common. 
3 Must know the data set coming from the server and the data set coming from the client side. 
There can be, although the data sets change together, a difference in the methods used for comparison. Therefor is there a 1:N cardinality between the change in data sets and the comparison method. That should be implemented using an interface.

The functions 'returning conclusion to the server side' and 'returning to the client side' change both independent from any other implementation. The server side does not have to have any implementation and it is recommended that the feedback to the client side is independent to the verification process itself. 
If the returning the conclusion to the server side has an implementation, then will it share most likely the connection and the information about the storage place with the retrieval of the data from the server side. That overlap should return in the design. So far have you not implemented the returning the conclusion to the server side, but that might be very useful. You can think about the next steps to execute on the server side after a login:
1. you might like to store the number of times someone has tried to login using the same computer or the same user name etc.
2. after each (number of) successful login(s) can you change the hashed password and the salt. At that time do you have the correct password in memory. 
(By the way: always use a salt. I have seen an application in which people were given a standardized default password and the administrators knew that hashed password out of their head. They could login with the passwords of the people who were not changing their password after the initial login.)
3. you can add the preferences of the user to the new session.
4. ...
This step can be quite complex and have its influence on the feedback to the client (you have failed to login more then three times...)
Therefor should it have an abstract class as the behaviour of the implementation can change.

In UML class diagram does it look like this:

[image: Class diagram LoginController]

I depicted the relationships between the LoginController and the server side classes as aggregations to show that the LoginController decides which implementation to use based on the data model or other configuration data used.